# Passing style parameters in query string

Tags: html

I have a simple html page with a div element in it.
The innerHTML property of the div is set through query String.
In query string I pass html strings,i.e.

```
<p style='font-size:20px;color:green;'> Sun rises in the east </p> etc...
```

I get the appropriate output.

However, if I pass color code in style attribute say, #00990a, I am not displayed any content.

Can someone help me through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if theres a color code that contains a `#`, everything after that will be treated fragment identifier. to avoid this you have to url-encode your parameter-value (replacing `#` with `%23` an d doing the same with other characters that have a special meaning (`@&%=?#...`)).

Finally your url should look like this:

```
PageUrl?Content=%3Cp+style%3D%27color%3A%23009900%27%3EContent%3C%2Fp%3E
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean? do you get any errors? if so, what exactly does the error-message say? depending on your server-side language and webserver you might need to url-decode the parameter again before outputting it on your side...

Comment: you're welcome. if this was the solution to your problem, please consider accepting it by klicking the tick-mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown us any code, I shall guess…

In a URI, `#` indicates the start of the fragment identifier (as `?` indicates the start of the query string). Your colour is terminated the query string and starting the fragment identifier. You need to URL encode any character that has special meaning in URLs. (`#` is `%23`).

---

Do make sure that you sanitise the passed HTML and CSS on the server though. It is very easy to expose yourself to XSS attacks otherwise.

Comment: My Code is as follows: PageUrl?Content=<p style='color:#009900'>Content</p>

Comment: Yeah, I was right, you need to encode your data before putting it into URIs.